# Make HTML table cell's content fit - without wrapping?

Tags: html, css, html-table, row, word-wrap

This is my situation :

- I'm currently in the process of finalizing a rather... huge web application (PHP with CodeIgniter, MySQL, Javascript+Ajax+Jquery and using various Javascript libraries - e.g. dataTables)

**The issue :**

- Let's say we've got a **table, fixed-width**.
- The first **column** is also **fixed-width**. (Let's say at `200px`)
- When the table is populated :

  - If the contents of the first column occupy less than 200px space, it's ok.
  - If the contents exceed those 200px then **the content is wrapped**, thus creating a "double line" effect and *higher rows* than I'd wished.

**Hint :**

- "Shrinking" a `very very very long line` to something like `very very very ...` is what I'm thinking. Is something like that even possible? Server-side?

How would you approach that? *(preferably in an elegant way - 'coz, yep, I admit that I have a few solutions in mind, none of which seems... user-friendly... lol)*

Comment: What is it that you'd like to happen?

Comment: @BillyMoat Just updated my initial post to give you the general idea.

Comment: Maybe something like this jQuery plugin? http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/

Comment: Maybe truncate at a certain point and just show the full thing on hovering a Read More link?

Comment: @BillyMoat Hmmm.. There really is a jQuery plugin for anything! lol. Thanks! I'm currently having a look into it.

Comment: @hsalama What you suggest is even closer to what I had in mind. I'm just checking if this type of thing has already been implemented (e.g. as part of a plugin, like BillyMoat mentioned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think doing a string-truncation is impossible serverside, if you are not using a monospace font so that the same number of characters always has the same width. What you could do is a client-side string-truncation:

(Nice code at [Calculate text width with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript)):

CSS:

```
#testing-div
{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

JS:

```
var test = document.getElementById("testing-div");
test.style.fontSize = fontSize;
var height = (test.clientHeight + 1) + "px";
var width = (test.clientWidth + 1) + "px";
```

You can loop through the entire length of the string, and keep adding a character to the body of `#testing-div`, calculating the width, and checking if it fits. Make sure you add the `...` if the string is too long.